# Can the main method used to start a JVM be determined from a core file?

Tags: java, jvm

On startup, a JVM finds a user specified class and runs the method contained therein with the signature "public static void main(String[])".

The thread executing the main method can obviously terminate while the JVM continues to run other threads that the main method had spawned.  Therefore, extracting a Java stack trace (e.g. "jstack" output) is not sufficient to find out the initial class from which the JVM was started.  I'm also not aware of other commands typically included in a JDK that will extract that information from a running JVM or core file.

I'm working on some automation for analysis of core files, and it would be helpful to understand the class from which a JVM was started, even when no threads are running code under that class at the time the core file was created.

Question: Do JVMs in general (and both Oracle and OpenJDK specifically) keep track of the class from which the main method was called?

Comment: A running JVM is a process in the OS and it starts a thread in which main() runs. The programmer controls threads thereafter but `The thread executing the main method can obviously terminate while the JVM continues` is wrong because every such thread is a child of the main thread. Kill the main thread and all dies unless some kind of scheduler system is used (in which case the OS would start new JVMs).

Comment: You've taken an issue with the semantics.  I'm sure you also understood the question.  Do you have any thoughts on the answer?

Comment: By the way, as it wasn't clear, with an Oracle JVM, calling something like Thread.run() in Java will instruct one of the JVM's internal threads to spawn the thread.  The thread is not spawned by thread that called Thread.run().  The thread running the user specified main method never actually spawns any other threads, it only signals the thread responsible for actually spawning new threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jinfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jinfo.html) utility (included in OpenJDK and Oracle JDK) can tell the main class. It works both for live JVMs and for core dumps.

E.g. here is how to find the Java command line from the core dump:

```
jinfo /path/to/java core.1234 | grep sun.java.command
```

Starting from JDK 9 `jinfo` works only for live processes while `jhsdb jinfo` works for core dumps.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!